# How to extract string from a log file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file and I want to write a bash script to parse out information from that log to another .txt file. I get stuck on how to allow user to choose which specific text they want.

My log file contain:

```
06 May 19 03:40:35 3 abCodeClearTrap Error Clear Trap (agent: 12367a12, chassis:12367a12, ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT, csssi: EXTIFG, clearedID: 0x089088394)
06 May 19 03:44:35 3 abCodeErrorTrap Error Trap (agent: 12368a15, chassis: 12368a15, ErrIdText: Skip this item, csssi: SSRSSR, clearedID: 0x089088394)
```

Say the user want to parse the date, time, agent, Clear, and ErrIDText.
So far I have written

```
file="home/docs/abc.log"
parse_log_data(){
while read line ; do
date=$( awk -F: '{print $1, $2, $3}' )
clock=$( awk -F: '{print $4}' )
id=${ awk -F : '{print $5}' )
agent=$( grep -o 'agent[^"]*' )
Clear=$( grep -o 'Clear[^"]*' )
errIdText=$( grep -o 'errIdText[^"]*' )
```

I am not sure if what I did is correct, anyhelp would greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you feeding data to your `awk` and `grep` commands? (hint: you aren't, the data is coming from the while loop)

Comment: `date=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')` for instance. Don't split on a colon since you just want the first three columns split by space. Then `clock` would be `clock=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}')`, rinse and repeat. Just take this chunk by chunk and work your way through it.

Comment: You will have better results on this site if you show your exact desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. On line #2 just substitute `echo` for whatever it is you're trying to do with these variables.

```
while IFS=, read date clock id agent errid clear; do
  echo $date $clock $id $agent $errid $clear
done < <(
  gawk -v OFS=, '{
    match($0, /agent: ([^,]+).*ErrIdText: ([^,]+).*clearedID: ([^)]+)/, a)
    print $1 FS $2 FS $3, $4, $5, a[1], a[2], a[3]
  }' home/docs/abc.log
)
```